# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity - Save datetime to csv malforms datestring

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

During a Azure Synapse / Datafactory pipeline I try to "simply" save a datetime as a string in a CSV file. Before save the datetime I want to format it, like "2021-04-13T00:00:00.000Z", where after "T" its always "00:00:00.000Z".

In a copy activity I add a new field in the source and format the datetime, using the formatDateTime function from Azure but I am not able to produce the result I expect. Moreover I came across multiple outputs I don't understand.

Here is what I do for debugging:
In copy activity "Source" I add multiple new fields that format the PipelineTriggerTime in different ways with different effects. I write these values into a CSV file as sink.
[image: Copy Activity new fields]

[image]

The following table shows the input, the dynamic values, the expected outcomes, and the actual outcomes.

|  | pipeline().TriggerTime | Dynamic Content | Expected Output | Actual Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-13T11:14:33.375Z | @formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000Z') | 2021-04-13T00:00:00.000Z | 04/13/2021 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-04-13T11:14:33.375Z | @formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') | 2021-04-13 11:14:33 | 2021-04-13 11:14:33 |
| 3 | 2021-04-13T11:14:33.375Z | @formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-ddTsomeText') | 2021-04-13TsomeText | 2021-04-13T33o14eTexA |
| 4 | 2021-04-13T11:14:33.375Z | @concat(formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'T00:00:00.000Z') | 2021-04-13T00:00:00.000Z | 04/13/2021 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 2021-04-13T11:14:33.375Z | @concat(formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'TsomeText') | 2021-04-13TsomeText | 2021-04-13TsomeText |

Honestly, the only non-suprising outputs for me are 2 and 5.
Is this explainable? The formatDateTime function should return a "string" but it seems to do something different (sometimes)..
Any other idea, how I could reach my goal, saving the string "2021-04-13T00:00:00.000Z" to a csv file in an Azure Copy Activity?

I am using Synapse Analytics, but the effects are the same for Data Factory, hence I added the latter to reach more people.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using the startOfDay() function rather than formatDateTime().

As for an explanation for your results, it's complicated. Have a look into the ISO 8601 standard, I've pasted a link below. Time zones can affect the conversions/formatting. I'd try a few things if you insisted on keeping the formatDateTime() function or for some reason startOfDay wasn't an option for you.

Record #1) Remove the Z at the end of your format argument. - I'd be curious if this resolves this one (note how the Z isn't brought over in record #2 and you didn't include a Z in that function argument?)

Record #3) You can't add additional text at the end of 'yyyy-MM-dd' - this is why I suggest you look into the ISO 8601 standard because that's what formatDateTime() and startOfDay() both support.

Record #4) Again, remove the Z, just like in #1. However, if it doesn't work, I have one other idea. It could be that the order of operations is behaving slightly different than we'd expect. Perhaps formatDateTime() formats it the way that you want it and then for some reason the concatenate function changes it to mm/dd/yyyy format before concatenating it with the 0's that you're looking to add. I'm not sure why it would be doing this, but I'm not sure what else it would be, so if it's not the Z and it's not this then I'm just as lost as you on this one.

Last thing to note is that if you want to add milliseconds you need to add a decimal after the seconds of the time. So your format would be hh:mm:ss.sss

Good luck!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: "You can't add additional text at the end" this might be the main problem with my approach, I wanted to have the 0s as "additional text" which seems not to work. StarOfDay is a good one.. The results confused me such, that I did never search for an alternative funciton. 
Removing the Z does not change anything. It is in 1, because the dateTimeString I need in the end should contain it (It should look like "pipeline().triggerTime", which also includes the "Z"). #2 does not include it, because I was playing around to see what the problem might be.

But thanks for your detailed answer so far!